# One-hot-encoding labels giving input labels

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to apply one-hot-encoding for a pandas dataframe but I can't give a categories argument. My idea is to have the corresponding between categories and the encoding, for example:

```
CATEGORIES = ['A','B','C']
Y = pd.get_dummies(data['Article_Topic_1']).values
```

For example, `Y` will be `[0,0,1]` for category `'A'`, but I would like to prescribe the encoding for `'A'` to be `[1,0,0]`.

If this is not possible, is there a way to prescribe the encoding and know the exact string that was there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can try using `scikit-learn` for the [one-hot encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)? 
Find [here](https://www.ritchieng.com/machinelearning-one-hot-encoding/) a comprehensive example.

Comment: Does this really answer the question? How exactly can you prescribe the encoding as the OP requested?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with `get_dummies()` directly. But how about just reorganizing the result? If I got your question correctly, you want to reorder the columns of the one-hot-encoded data to match a prescribed ordering.

```
categories = ["A", "B", "C"]
Y = pd.get_dummies(data["Article_Topic_1"])
Y = Y[categories].values
```

---

Here a function checking some of the assumptions made that this solution works.

```
def get_dummies_for_coding(series, ordering):
    # Ordering must contain only values present in series.
    assert(len(set(ordering)-set(series.unique()))==0)
    # It's easier to work with series here, because pd.get_dummies()
    # will operate with string prefixes for data-frames, which make
    # things a bit more complicated.
    assert(isinstance(series, pd.Series))
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(series)
    dummies = dummies[ordering]
    #return dummies
    return dummies.values

# Example
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "foo"],
                   ["a", "bar"],
                   ["b", "bar"],
                   ["a", "baz"],
                   ["b", "bar"]],
                  columns=["colA", "colB"])
orderingA = ["b", "a"]
orderingB = ["baz", "bar", "foo"]

ret = get_dummies_for_coding(df["colA"], orderingA)
print(ret)
ret = get_dummies_for_coding(df["colB"], orderingB)
print(ret)
```